# What can be the reason on why the C program is not freeing up the memory even after closing the files and freeing the pointers?

Tags: c, memory, ram

The following function is being called multiple times from the main function. I am monitoring the RAM usage of the program. Every time a call is being made to this function the RAM memory usage increases. The problem is every time the function terminates and I close the file, the RAM memory usage still keeps on increasing. So, after a few calls to this function the system kills the process because of using too much memory. Can you please help me with this problem?

Why is the memory not being cleared even after closing the file? Is there any solution for this problem? Please bear with my poor coding skills. I am an amateur at C and this code has been highly modified so you may find some redundant variables.

```
void find_path(char* hope_key_node)
{


    char input_list[100];
    char affected_dff_list[100];
    char output_dependency[100];            // file name for storing the output cone of dependency
    char input_no[100];             // file name for storing the number of inputs in each output cone of dependency

    strcpy(input_list, circuit_name);
    strcat(input_list, "/");
    strcpy(affected_dff_list, input_list);





    int inNum; // Stores the number of nodes in each output cone of dependency
    memset(output_dependency, '\0', sizeof(output_dependency));
    memset(input_no, '\0', sizeof(input_no));
    strcpy(output_dependency, circuit_name);        // This creates a new directory inside <circuit_name>/dependency/
    strcat(output_dependency, "/dependency/");
    //strcat(output_dependency, hope_key_node);


    strcpy(input_no, output_dependency);
    strcat(input_no, "inNum_" );
    strcat(input_no, hope_key_node);
    printf("%s\n",input_no);
    input_num = fopen(input_no,"w");            // For storing the number of nodes in each output cone of dependency

    for(int ii = 0; ii < NO_OF_OUTPUT; ii++)  // This loop iterates over the array of strings 'output_name[]' which contains the list of output nodes.
    {   
        /*strcpy(output_dependency, circuit_name);      // This creates a new file (of the name of output) inside <circuit_name>/dependency/<hope_key_node>/
        strcat(output_dependency, "/dependency/");
        strcat(output_dependency, hope_key_node );

        strcat(output_dependency, "/" );        
        strcat(output_dependency, output_name[ii]);

        output_history = fopen(output_dependency,"w");
        printf("\n%s\n",output_dependency);
        if( output_history == NULL )  
            {   
            perror ("Error opening file: output_dependency: ");
            exit(0);
        }*/


        inNum = 0;      // Resetting the value of inNum for each cone

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)                // Resetting the color values of all the nodes so that all the nodes are unvisited.
        {
                node_array[i].color=0;
            }   

        /*for(int i=0;i<count;i++)                
        {
                printf("%s\t%d\n",node_array[i].name,node_array[i].color);
            }   
        */

        char **track_path = (char **)malloc(MAX_NODE * sizeof(char *));   // Array of strings which contains the track path diverging from a specific output (ii th output)

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NODE; i++)
        {
            track_path[i] = (char *)malloc((100) * sizeof(char));
        }

        //char track_path[120000][100];
        int path_counter = 0;               // Stores the index which is used in the track_path
        for(int jj = 0; jj< count; jj++)
        {
            if(!(strcmp(output_name[ii],node_array[jj].name)))
            {
                strcpy(track_path[path_counter],node_array[jj].name);
                //fprintf(path_history,"%s\t====>", node_array[jj].name);
                //fprintf(dff_history,"%s\t====>", node_array[jj].name);
                //fprintf(output_history,"%s\t====>", node_array[jj].name);
                //printf("%s**\n",node_array[jj].name);
                path_counter++;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Shit storm. Please decode this at your own risk. It may lead to temporary loos of sanity.

        while(path_counter>0)
        {
            char temp[200];
            strcpy(temp,track_path[0]); 
            for(int mm = 0; mm <= path_counter-2; mm++)
            {
                strcpy(track_path[mm],track_path[mm+1]);
            }
            path_counter--;

            for(int jj = 0; jj < count; jj++)
            {   

                if(!(strcmp(temp,node_array[jj].name)) && strcmp(temp,hope_key_node))
                {
                    //fprintf(output_history,"%s\t", node_array[jj].name);     // Printing the output code of dependency
                    //fprintf(output_history,"%s\n", node_array[jj].name);
                    inNum++;

                    /*if(!(strcmp(node_array[jj].type, "DFF")))
                    {
                        fprintf(dff_history,"%s\t", node_array[jj].name);
                        /*for(int aa = 0; aa < dff_count; aa++)
                        {
                            if(!(strcmp(DFF_list[aa],node_array[jj].name)))
                            {
                                dff_dependency_matrix[ii][aa] = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }*/

                    //printf("******************************************************************************/n");
                    //printf("-----%s\t%d\n",node_array[jj].name,node_array[jj].no_of_input);
                    if(node_array[jj].no_of_input > 0)
                    {
                        for(int kk = 0; kk < node_array[jj].no_of_input; kk++)
                        {
                            {
                                //printf("\n++++%s\t\n", node_array[jj].name_input[kk]);
                                //printf("\n****%s\t%d\n",node_array[node_array[jj].index_of_input[kk]].name,node_array[node_array[jj].index_of_input[kk]].color);

                                if(node_array[node_array[jj].index_of_input[kk]].color == 0)
                                {   

                                    if(path_counter>0)
                                    {
                                        for(int mm = path_counter-1; mm >= 0; mm--)
                                        {
                                            strcpy(track_path[mm+1],track_path[mm]);
                                        }       
                                    }
                                    strcpy(track_path[0], node_array[jj].name_input[kk]);
                                    //printf("@@@@%s\t", node_array[jj].name_input[kk]);

                                    path_counter++;
                                    node_array[node_array[jj].index_of_input[kk]].color = 1;
                                }   
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    /*printf("\ntrack path \n");
                    for (int z = 0; z<path_counter;z++)
                        printf("%s\t",track_path[z]);
                    printf("\n\n");
                    */

                    else
                    {
                        //fprintf(path_history,"%s\t", node_array[jj].name);
                        /*for(int xx = 0; xx< NO_OF_OUTPUT; xx++)
                        {
                            if(!(strcmp(node_array[jj].name, output_name[xx])))
                            {
                                cone_of_dependency[ii][xx] = '1';
                            }
                        }   */
                    }   
                }
            }

        }

        fprintf(input_num,"%s\t%d\n",output_name[ii], inNum);
        //fprintf(path_history,"\n\n\n");
        //fprintf(dff_history,"\n\n\n");
        //fprintf(output_history,"\n\n\n");     //Do not change this. Other codes will throw segmentation error.

        free(track_path);
        //fclose(output_history);

    }

    fclose(input_num);


}
```

Comment: Where do you `free` the memory you `malloc`? ***Every*** `malloc` call needs a corresponding `free` call.

Comment: At the end of the function when that memory is no more in use. For instance in this function track_path is being malloc and is freed at the end of the function.

Comment: `track_path[i] = (char *)malloc((100) * sizeof(char));` has no corresponding`free()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the lines:

```
    char **track_path = (char **)malloc(MAX_NODE * sizeof(char *));   // Array of strings which contains the track path diverging from a specific output (ii th output)

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NODE; i++)
    {
        track_path[i] = (char *)malloc((100) * sizeof(char));
    }
```

you are allocating memory from the heap.

With

```
    free(track_path);
```

you deallocate `track_path`, but not the `track_path[i]`. So memory usage keeps increasing...

Instead, do:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NODE; i++)
    {
        free(track_path[i]);
    }
    free(track_path);
```

Note: it is considered harmful to cast the result of malloc. It is not necessary either.

Comment: What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: See my edit to dellocate them...but you could have thought of that yourself, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working properly. Its a shame that I missed that.